¿Cómo se hace la inversa de código unicode a carácter?
Si con TextBoxInput.charCodeAt(0) se accede al número unicode  de un carácter ¿Cómo se hace la inversa de código unicode a carácter?


function CompruebaNumero(){
    var TextBoxInput = "" + document.getElementById("TextBoxInput").value;
    if ( TextBoxInput != "" ){
        var Codigo = TextBoxInput.charCodeAt(0);
        alert(Codigo);
    }
    document.getElementById("TextBoxInput").value = "";
}
<input id="TextBoxInput" type="text" value="" maxlength="1" style="width: 120px;" onkeyup="CompruebaNumero()" />




El inverso de charCodeAt() es String.fromCharCode()


function CompruebaNumero(){
    var TextBoxInput = "" + document.getElementById("TextBoxInput").value;
    if ( TextBoxInput != "" ){
        var Codigo = String.fromCharCode(TextBoxInput);
        alert(Codigo);
    }
    document.getElementById("TextBoxInput").value = "";
}
<input id="TextBoxInput" type="text" value="" maxlength="3" style="width: 120px;" onblur="CompruebaNumero()" />



